# Convert java fields name to Hibernate name

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, reflection

I am using reflection to get the fields

`Field[] testContent = menu.getClass().getDeclaredFields();`

which returns me variables like

`fieldId` `fieldName`

and so on.

So I need to convert them in Hibernate style like

`FIELD_ID`, `FIELD_NAME`

So is there anything ready I can use ,because I was thinking of using Regular expressions to split it but I am hoping there is something already there.

Comment: Could provide more context to what you would like to achieve with that?

Comment: Do you just want "Hibernate style", or do you want to dynamically map the tables generated by Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guava provides such functionality:

```
 System.out.println(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE, "fieldName"));
```

Output is FIELD_NAME

Answer (score 0):

The names depend on the used Hibernate [naming strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html). Depending on the version and what you are trying to achieve, you could try to use the public API of the naming strategy you are using to get the table names directly from the Java classes, instead of using reflection, e.g. `classToTableName` for the [default naming strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html#classToTableName(java.lang.String)).